# Python Flask unable to get past CORS

Tags: python, flask, cors, flask-cors

I have the following script written in python

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources=r'/chat', headers='Content-Type')


@app.route("/chat")
def chat():
  print(request)
  request.get_data()
  data = json.loads(request.data)
  response = chatbot.get_response(str(data['message']))
  response_data = response.serialize()
  response = jsonify({'data': response_data})
  return response
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8900, debug=True)
```

I am calling this API from a JavaScript frontend running on http://localhost:8080

I am using Google Chrome and get the following error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8900/chat/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I also get the following the log message in the Python Console for each request

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Mar/2020 15:12:00] "?[33mOPTIONS /chat/ HTTP/1.1?[0m" 404 -
```

I am getting really frustrated because even if I change my code to

```
@app.route("/chat")
def chat():
  print(request)
  request.get_data()
  data = json.loads(request.data)
  response = chatbot.get_response(str(data['message']))
  response_data = response.serialize()
  response = jsonify({'data': response_data})
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
  return response
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting the headers like this instead?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources=r'/chat', headers='Content-Type')


@app.route("/chat")
def chat():
  print(request)
  request.get_data()
  data = json.loads(request.data)
  response = chatbot.get_response(str(data['message']))
  response_data = response.serialize()
  response = jsonify({'data': response_data})
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization'
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'
  return response
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8900, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I still get exactly the same error. BTW I all so get the folloiwng log message in the console. 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Mar/2020 15:12:00] "?[33mOPTIONS /chat/ HTTP/1.1?[0m" 404 -

Comment: @PrestonDocks I edited my answer, not sure if it will work, but I see in most places the headers are set like in my new answer, so it may be worth a shot...

Comment: I found another problem which along with your code has fixed the problem. So Thank you. Take care and keep washing your hands.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! You too!